# Why are there always at least 10 sessions for a postgreSQL database? Why can't they be terminated?

Tags: postgresql, session, ecto, terminate

**Original aim**: rename a database using `ALTER DATABASE` via psql.
**Problem**: rename fails due to other sessions accessing target database.
 ・All terminals/applications I am aware of have been closed.

・querying `pg_stat_activity` shows that there are 10 processes(=sessions?) accessing the db.
・The `username` for each session is the same user I have been using for psql and for some local phoenix and django apps. The `client_addr` is also local host for all of them.
・When I use `pg_terminate_backend`, on any of the pids, another process gets immediately spawned.
・After restarting my pc, 10 processes are again spawned.

**Concern**: As I can't account for these 10 processes that I can't get rid of, I think I'm misunderstanding how postgres works somewhere.

**Question**: Why do 10 session/processes connected to a particular one of my databases, and why can't I terminate them using pg_terminate_backend?

Note: In the phoenix project I set up recently, I set the and set the `pool_size` of the Repo config to 10 - which makes me think it's related...but I'm pretty sure that project isn't running in any way.

## Update - Solved

As a_horse_with_no_name suggested, the by doing the following I was able to put a stop to the 10 mystery sessions.

  (1) prevent login of user responsible for the sessions (identifiable by querying `pg_stat_activity`), by doing `alter user .... with nologin` 
 
 (2)-running pg_terminate_backend on each of the session's pids.

After those steps I was able to change the table name.

The remaining puzzle is, how did those sessions get in that status in the first place... from the contents of pg_stat_activity, the `wait_event` value for each was `clientRead`.
From [this post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/251937/query-hanging-in-clientread-and-blocking-all-others), it seems that the application may have been forcibly stopped halfway through a transaction or something, leaving postgres hanging.

Comment: It's probably your Phoenix and Django apps that automatically re-connect if the session is killed. You could try to prevent login of that user using `alter user .... with nologin` then kill those sessions manually. As the user is no longer allowed to login, any attempt from those apps will fail

Comment: Certainly sounds like a connection pooler which automatically reconnects.  If it ain't the pooler you already know about, then I guess it must be one you don't know about.